# Switching position of reledmac footnote number in the main body of the text

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

When using `reledmac` and familiar footnotes, the footnote number is set on the LEFT side of the lemma text, not on the right:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[series={A,B},draft]{reledmac}
\newcommand{\annotation}[1]{\footnoteA{#1}}
\newcommand{\variant}[2]{\Afootnote{#1 \ #2}}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering

\pstart
I will put this \edtext{footnote}{\annotation{Some obscure source.}} here.
\pend

\end{document}
```

[image: footnote error]

For me at least this is an unexpected behavior, for I would expect the footnote to go to the right of the lemma text.

I would like to have the footnote number on the right, but I have seen nothing in the `reledmac` documentation relating to this. Do you have any ideas for changing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you use familiar footnote inside second argument of `\edtext`. But you need `\edtext` only for critical footnote, not for familiar.

Just do

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[series={A,B},draft]{reledmac}
\newcommand{\annotation}[1]{\footnoteA{#1}}
\newcommand{\variant}[2]{\Afootnote{#1 \ #2}}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering

\pstart
I will put this footnote\annotation{Some obscure source.} here.
\pend

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Maieul, I super appreciate your attention to the package. `reledmac` is amazing.